# Gradient in batch-size

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient, batch-normalization

When we set a batch-size, after each sample of batch passed we take the gradient but wait until last sample of batch to passed and then propagate the sum of gradient of them through the network? Am I correct or
not?

If it isn't and we propagate after each pass of sample so what is the benefits of batch? Please, someone give me an explanation.

Comment: Actually we don't take the gradient after each sample  but compute the sum of the errors and once a batch is completed, then you take the overall gradient and backpropagate. Will write answer asap

Comment: Yeah, that is it. I mean take errors and then propagate gradient of sum of errors. is it certainly?

Comment: I have posted an answer, please feel free to accept it if this is ok for you :)

Comment: @MysteryGuy Ok thanks. maybe i can get a repu also on question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When training neural networks, backpropagation requires the computation of many gradients and it can be computationnally heavy. In order to minimize that load, the weights are only updated (i.e. the backpropagation is done) after a certain amount of samples, that's called batch (or mini-batch, if number of samples is low) gradient descent.

So, the loss function is of course computed after each training example and summed up for all the samples in the batch, then backpropagation is applied on the overall loss of the batch.

You can also update the weights after each sample, this is called stochastic gradient descent

Comment: I think the is not just the heavy load of computation, it is also because of really congested changes of direction of gradient in the way.

Comment: @ja0k0010 Yes you have also vanishing and exploding gradient problem... But if you have a deep neural network, computing the derivatives can takes time...